# Why does decrementation becomes more than -1 at the 2nd time of setInterval?

Tags: javascript

```
$(document).ready(function(e) {

    var count=10;
    setInterval(timer, 1000); 
    var green = true;

        function timer()
        {

              if (count < 1)
              {
                 count = 10;
                 setInterval(timer, 1000);

                 green ? green=false : green = true;                    
              }

              $('#tl').empty();

              if(green)
                $('#tl').append(count).css('color', '#090');

              else
                $('#tl').append(count).css('color', '#F00');

              count = count - 1;
        }
});
```

This is a simple traffic light  counter. At first it runs as 10 9 8 7 6 5 4 3 2 1, the next time it become 10 8 6 4 2 0, then 10 7 4 1

Comment: You don't have to call `setInterval(timer, 1000);` again

Comment: `green = !green` is better than `green ? green=false : green = true`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to create/set it more than one time:

```
     if (count < 1)
         {
             count = 10;
             // setInterval(timer, 1000); < -- remove this line

             green ? green=false : green = true;                    
         }
```

Answer (score 0):

I realised @cherniv already gave the answer which was a typo in the original code but it wondered for a bit why it was giving as you said

> At first it runs as 10 9 8 7 6 5 4 3 2 1, the next time it become 10 8 6 4 2 0, then 10 7 4 1

So basically you are doing something like a function calling a function (almost recursion like but ofcourse javascript context makes it different). The function `setInterval(timer, 1000)` is being called from within itself again.

So the first time it goes about **10 levels deep** giving you

> 10 9 8 7 6 5 4 3 2 1

The next time when `count < 1` is true the `setInterval(timer, 1000)` functions which are already **running in the background** (so to say) fire almost instantly **with very little time differences between the two (since they started firing the same way too)**.

Thus this leads to the `counter` variable decreasing by **2 instead of 1** with very little difference apart. giving you

> 10 8 6 4 2 0

and so on for the next intervals where intervals decrease successively.

Hope that helps **understand why its behaving that way** :)